# Spring boot 2.7.0 bean could not be found using IntelliJ idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Solution:
I just spend a lot of time with the same problem.
I figured out that it's bug in IntelliJ with spring > 2.7.0 and will be fixed in release 222.2889.
For now, I just reduce my spring version to 2.6.8

[Bug link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-294599/Spring-Boot-after-update-to-SB-version-270-the-autoconfigured-beans-appear-as-not-available-for-autowiring)

Comment: If you want to submit a self-answered question (and these are very welcome), please follow the standard format, describe the problem and the solution.